# eAccelerator disk cache size

Tags: cache, php

I am using eAccelerator to cache my PHP opcodes. I have the disk cache set to /var/cache/eAccelerator. How can I limit the size of the cache? It's already grown to 1.5 GiB and keeps growing!

Comment: Really? Nobody knows? I guess I'll just write my own...

Answer (score 1):

My *guess*, based on the eAccelerator [documentation](http://eaccelerator.net/wiki/Settings), is that it's caching more than you want it to.

I *think* what you want to do is flip

```
eaccelerator.shm_only = "0"
```

to

```
eaccelerator.shm_only = "1"
```

Maybe :)

Or you might consider `quota`-ing the cache directory? Not sure if that would backfire, or if it would cap its size, however.

Also, you might look at the [compile-time](http://eaccelerator.net/wiki/CompileConfiguration) option `--with-eaccelerator-shared-memory`. Not sure if that's related, but if scripts are storing results in cache, too - it could be an issue?